# Run Specs error: Couldn't load the Unicode tables for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, activesupport

I tried to run my specs but I got the following error:

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...

1) FinancialAccountsQuery parcial_future_releases LIMIT_DATE_FILTER transactions 
 Failure/Error: let(:financial_account) { FactoryGirl.create(:financial_account_with_church) }
 IOError:
   Couldn't load the Unicode tables for UTF8Handler (dump format error(0x6b)), ActiveSupport::Multibyte is unusable
 # ./spec/queries/financial_accounts_query_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/queries/financial_accounts_query_spec.rb:106:in `create_transaction'
 # ./spec/queries/financial_accounts_query_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I tried to drop all the databases with rake `db:drop`, then create them again with `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`, but nothing seems to solve it.

My `database.yml`

```
development:
    adapter: "mysql2"
    encoding: "utf8"
    database: "ibc1"
    username: "root"
    password: ""
    host: 127.0.0.1

test:
  adapter: "mysql2"
  encoding: "utf8"
  database: "gi_test"
  username: "root"
  password: ""
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

Anyone has any idea to solve this ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: This comment may be helpful for you:  https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/323#issuecomment-5118194

Comment: Well, I just realized that the problem was in my Ruby installed on Linux Mint I used to have ram problems.